# TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'

Tags: python-3.x, hex, python-imaging-library

I would like to convert the below hex sequences to images, in the process of sifting through quite a number of problems that are similar to mine none have come close as to that solved in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33989302/13648455, my code is below, where could I be going wrong?

```
data = "2a2b2c2a2b2c2a2b2c2a2b2cb1"
buf = io.StringIO()    
for line in data.splitlines():
    line = line.strip().replace(" ", "")
    if not line:
        continue
    bytez = binascii.unhexlify(line)
    buf.write(bytez)

with open("image.jpg", "wb") as f:
    f.write(buf.getvalue())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`io.StringIO()` creates a string object which yields a text stream.
You need `io.BytesIO()` instead, which creates a bytes object to which you can write your binary data:

```
buf = io.BytesIO()

...

buf.write(bytez)
```

See also [io — Core tools for working with streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html)